# Regular expression in dbGetQuery does not work

Tags: sql, r, regex

I want to get all rows in my database where a condition with regular expressions is met. The variable should start with "J12", "J13", "J14" or "J15".
This was my attempt:

```
Data <- dbGetQuery(db, 
           "SELECT * FROM 'XXX.XXXX.XXX'
                   WHERE TYPE = 'xyz' AND [xyz_DIAG] LIKE '^J1[2-5]' ")
```

Then a data.frame with 0 rows is returned.
When I send the query

```
Data <- dbGetQuery(db, 
           "SELECT * FROM 'XXX.XXXX.XXX'
                   WHERE TYPE = 'xyz'")
```

I get a quite large data.frame and then I call
`Data %>% setDT %>% .[str_detect(xyz_DIAG, "^J1[2-5]")]` and I get the expected result because in fact there are many rows that fulfill that regexp. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: What DB is it? MySQL?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Yes, MySQL

Comment: Then `AND [xyz_DIAG] REGEXP '^J1[2-5]'` should work

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the differences between the databases. I connect to the database in this way: `db <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), 
                     'Database/db.sqlite')`

Comment: When I try `REGEX`, `no such function: REGEXP` is returned.

Comment: I checked the [source code](https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite) and it seems there is no regex support. SQLite has no regex support built-in, one should implement it as a UDF. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: Oh, good to know, thank you! What a pity.

Comment: See https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/pull/266, too, looks like the issue is not resolved yet.

Comment: So,all you can do is something like `AND ([xyz_DIAG] LIKE 'J12%' OR [xyz_DIAG] LIKE 'J13%' OR [xyz_DIAG] LIKE 'J14%' OR [xyz_DIAG] LIKE 'J15%')`.

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, `REGEXP` operator has not been added to `RSQLITE`, see [this pull request](https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/pull/266).

You thus need to "unwrap" the regex and use ORed `LIKE`:

```
Data <- dbGetQuery(db, 
       "SELECT * FROM 'XXX.XXXX.XXX'
               WHERE TYPE = 'xyz' AND ([xyz_DIAG] LIKE 'J12%' OR [xyz_DIAG] LIKE 'J13%' OR [xyz_DIAG] LIKE 'J14%' OR [xyz_DIAG] LIKE 'J15%') ")
```